# Count number of identical pairs

Tags: algorithm, sorting

An identical pair in array are 2 indices `p,q` such that

`0<=p<q<N` and `array[p]=array[q]` where `N` is the length of the array.

Given an unsorted array, find the number identical pairs in the array.

My solution was to sort the array by values,
keeping track of indices.

Then for every index `p` in sorted array, count all `q<N` such that and

```
sortedarray[p].index < sortedarray[q].index and 
sortedarray[p] = sortedarray[q]
```

Is this the correct approach. I think the complexity would be

```
O(N log N) for sorting based on value  +

O(N^2) for counting the newsorted array that satisfies the condition.
```

This means I am still looking at `O(N^2)`. Is there a better way ?

Another thought that came was for every P binary search the sorted array for all Q that satisfies the condition. Would that not reduce the complexity of the second part to `O(Nlog(N))`

Here is my code for second part

```
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){

                    int j=i+1;

            while( j<N && sortedArray[j].index > sortedArray[i].index &&
                   sortedArray[j].item == sortedArray[i].item){

                        inversion++;
                        j++;
            }
      }
   return inversion;
```

@Edit: I think, I mistook the complexity of second part to be `O(N^2)`.

As in every iteration in while loop, no rescan of elements from indices 0-i occurs, linear time is required for scanning the sorted array to count the inversions. The total complexity is therefore

`O(NlogN)` for sorting and `O(N)` for linear scan count in sorted array.

Comment: Since sorting will put equal values together, you don't need to check all `q`, just those that are near `p`. If you use a stable sorting algorithm you don't even need to perform the first test.

Comment: Correct, I will need to check values near p, for every p in 0<p<N so wont that make it O(N^2) ( consider an array of all equal values )

Comment: The fact that the array is sorted implies that you can scan it in one single pass. So it's not O(n^2) but O(n). As a counter example, insertion sort is O(n^2) because for each element it has to scan the whole array.

Comment: @mdm, could you please refer my code for second part, may be I missed your point but I still feel second part should have quadratic time complexity.

Comment: @SREEPRASADGOVINDANKUTTY There is a quadratic number of pairs but you can compute it in `O(n)`

Comment: @SREEPRASADGOVINDANKUTTY I responded below, hopefully I was clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are partially correct.  Sorting the array via Merge Sort or Heapsort will take `O(n lg n)`.  But once the array is sorted, you can make a single pass through to find all identical pairs.  This single pass is an `O(n)` operation.  So the total complexity is:

`O(n lg n + n) = O(n lg n)`

Comment: i think single pass wont give all values, it will give me count of all sequential values in sortedarray that satisfies the condition.

Comment: How difficult is it to find identical pairs in this array: `[1, 5, 7, 7, 10, 13, 13, 20]` ?

Comment: Tim, could you please refer my code, I may have missed your point but  I cannot see linear time cost invariant  for the second part.

Comment: @SREEPRASADGOVINDANKUTTY Once you sort the array you can count the number of times each value appears in the array in `O(n)`  because equal values will be contiguous. You can compute the number of pairs easily. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As Tim points out in his response, the complexity of finding the pairs within a sorted array is `O(n)` and not `O(n^2)`.

To convince yourself of this, think about a typical `O(n^2)` algorithm: **[Insertion Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort)**.

An animated example can be found [here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0f/Insertion-sort-example-300px.gif).

As you can see in the gif, the reason why this algorithm is quadratic, is because, for each element, it has to check the whole array to ensure where such element will have to go (this **includes** previous elements in the array!).

On the hand, in you case, you have an ordered array: e.g. `[0,1,3,3,6,7,7,9,10,10]`

In this situation, you will start scanning (pairwise) from the beginning, and (because of the fact that the array is ordered) you know that once an element is scanned and you pointers proceed, there cannot be any reason to rescan previous elements in the future, because otherwise you would have not proceeded in the first place.

Hence, you scan the whole array only once: `O(n)`

Comment: This means I mistook the complexity of code for the second part to be O(N^2). As my index "j"  is always greater than index "i", no rescan of elements from 0-i occurs and the complexity is actually O(N) . Correct ?

Comment: @SREEPRASADGOVINDANKUTTY Correct!

Answer (score 0):

If you can allocate more memory you can get some gains.

You can reach `O(n)` by using a hash table which maps any values in the array to a counter indicating how often you already saw this value.

If the number of allowed values is integral and in a limited range you can directly use an array instead of a hash table. The index of value `i` being `i` itself. In that case the complexity would be `O(n+m)` where `m` is the number of allowed values (because you must first set to `0` all entries in the array and then look through all the array entries to count pairs).

Both methods gives you the number of identical values for each values in your array. Let's call this number `nv_i` the number of appearance of the value `i` in the array. Then the number of pairs of value `i` is: `(nv_i)*(nv_i-1)/2`.

You can pair:

```
1st  i with nv_i-1 others
2nd  i with nv_i-2 others
...
last i with 0
```

And `(nv_i-1)+(nv_i-2)+...+0 = (nv_i)*(nv_i-1)/2`

Comment: do we need another hash map again, Wont a linear scan give me the count of the indices that satisfies the condition. Please refer my code and TIm and mdm 's comments

Comment: @SREEPRASADGOVINDANKUTTY If you sort the array, you don't need the hashmap. You can just run through the array and compute the `nv_i`. But the hashmap will give you all the `nv_i` without sorting. So you go from `O(n*log(n))` to `O(n)` for the whole algorithm.

Comment: How are you updating the counter ?  It cannot be frequency of how often the value is seen as the conditions of indices and value may not be satisfied.

Comment: @SREEPRASADGOVINDANKUTTY Yes, `nv_i` is what you name *frequency*. What conditions would not be satified ? Please remark that the specific index of a value doesn't matter to count the number of distinct pairs. What you need is just to know the existence of a sequence of values `i` of a given length `nv_i`.

Answer (score 0):

I've been thinking about this.... I think that if you "embed" the `==` condition into your sorting algorithm, then, the complexity is still O(n lg n).